# How can I change which driver is used for a sound card?

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 with the 4.4.0-113 kernel.

I have two different XMOS-based USB sound cards, one works perfectly and plays DSD files as expected. The other works, but is not recognized as an XMOS device, so a less than ideal driver is loaded for it.

How can I change it so that the same driver is loaded and used for both devices?

lsusb for both devices:

The card with the desired driver:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 20b1:000a XMOS Ltd
```

The card with the less-optimal driver:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 16d0:09dd MCS
```

Output from asound:

Card with proper driver:

```
card 4: x20 [xCORE USB Audio 2.0], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Card with improper driver:

```
card 3: mDSD [Encore mDSD], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Edit to document solution:

Following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch08s06.html), I downloaded the kernel source, modified, and compiled.

I added the vendor and device ID from the lsusb output to the relevant section in the kernel source

```
../sound/usb/quirks.c
```

Specifically, a line for the Encore mDSD:

```
    case USB_ID(0x16d0, 0x09dd): /* Encore mDSD */
    case USB_ID(0x20b1, 0x000a): /* Gustard DAC-X20U */
    case USB_ID(0x20b1, 0x2009): /* DIYINHK DSD DXD 384kHz USB to I2S/DSD */
    case USB_ID(0x20b1, 0x2023): /* JLsounds I2SoverUSB */
    case USB_ID(0x20b1, 0x3023): /* Aune X1S 32BIT/384 DSD DAC */
    case USB_ID(0x2616, 0x0106): /* PS Audio NuWave DAC */
        if (fp->altsetting == 3)
            return SNDRV_PCM_FMTBIT_DSD_U32_BE;
        break;
```

Then I compiled the driver, installed, rebooted and the card works perfectly with native DSD up to DSD256.

Comment: What is the output of `lsusb` for both devices?

Comment: @CL. I added the lsusb and aplay outputs to the original post

Comment: Please show the output of `lsusb -v` for the mDSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard that would allow the driver to detect DSD devices. Each device must be [listed in the driver](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/sound/usb/quirks.c#n1320), and so far, nobody has known about the "mDSD".

The only way to get the mDSD to work is to recompile the driver.

Comment: Do I add the card's vendor and device id's to that source then recompile the driver then compile the kernel with my altered driver?

Comment: Yes, but the driver is part of the kernel. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I found this walkthrough: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel is that what I should do?

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu, but that looks OK.

Comment: Thanks! I followed a [different guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch08s06.html) and got everything working. Details added to original question.